# Regex to capture string after "http://" but before "/"

Tags: regex

I have a list of URLs like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/cats
http://stackoverflow.com/blah
http://stackoverflow.com/cats/dogs
```

What is a regex that would let me capture only the "stackoverflow.com" part?

Comment: Based on the post details, a possible suggestion is `http://([^/]*)`

Comment: What is your environment? Where will you be running regex? any language or particular text editor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the part after the server name:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/(.*)
```

If you want the server name and path:

```
http://(.*)
```

If you want only the server name:

```
http://([^/]+)/
```

Note if you are using sed, you will want a delimiter that's not a "/".